# Problems installing NetBeans 8.1. I have eclipse in my computer and tried installing NetBeans but errors kept coming

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

[image]

I have been using Java in using eclipse for the past few weeks and decided to use NetBeans instead. However I kept getting these messages: first one was on the left. After clicking Yes then I get the second window. After clicking disable module and continue the installing just stop! Help please :)

Comment: It appears to me that the Java files cannot be found.

Comment: It seems that your JDK is unistalled? Check environement variables in Windows, if JAVA_HOME is specified, it should point to an installed jdk. Otherwise you are able to customize the search for netbeans by editing the netbeans.conf file in program dir.

Comment: i can't seem to edit the netbeans.conf file :(

Comment: @NicholasMa probably because you put it in Program Files and don't have the rights - copy it to a different folder, modify it and copy it back to where it should be.